# Wifi stopped working on Acer Aspire 3680 using 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless, acer, atheros, aspire

A while ago the WiFi on my Acer Aspire 3680 just stopped working. The switch is on and it can see my network, but it will not connect. It has an Atheros AR2413 802.11bg NIC.

`rfkill` shows there are no soft blocks in place.

```
sudo rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here is what `iwconfig` said:

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traced the issue to the SmartLink proprietary modem driver. It basically broke my ability to sign onto a WiFi network. Disabling it immediately restored wifi.

[image: Additional Drivers]