# Wireless networking features not working on 12.10 dual booting with Windows 8

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, dual-boot, lenovo

Before I begin, I should probably say that I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so please forgive me if I miss something obvious.

I recently figured out how to dual boot Ubuntu 12.10 with Windows 8 on a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 13. However, when I tried to connect to my home WiFi network through the icon at the top right, I saw the message "No network devices available." I suspect this may be a driver issue. I checked in Software Sources under Additional Drivers, and found that no drivers were listed. Does anyone know anything about this?

Update: I believe that `iwconfig` was the correct command, because it returned this:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your network card is disabled? Otherwise run `ifconfig`. What does that show you?

Comment: if i remember right i believe the command is actually `iwconfig`. What does that return?

Answer (score 0):

Try the method stated in this Q&A here --- [[link]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106384/wifi-stopped-working-on-acer-aspire-3680-using-11-10) ---

**EDIT: New Link**

Try this method --- [[new link]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized) ---

Comment: This might work, but for some reason, the "Additional Drivers" tool was not installed by default. I apparently have to download and install it, which is impossible without an internet connection.

Comment: Try this--click the ubuntu icon, type `Software Sources`, open that and you might be able to access "Additional Drivers"

Comment: My driver isn't listed; in fact, no drivers are.

Comment: I edited my solution. If you could confirm that this method works or not, I would much appreciate it. I have the same laptop, and before I attempt to get dual boot, I would like to know if this worked.